# CSLA.NET information

Tags: csla

I am looking for some literature on CSLA.NET, does anyone have any direct links to/for this framework?

If someone also has time would you mind providing insight into this platform.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

One of the best sources of detailed information regarding CSLA is this book, written by Rocky:
[Expert C# 2008 Business Objects](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210192)

In this book, Rocky explains in detail not only how to apply the CSLA framework, but also how it is constructed.

Unfortunately this edition of the book only covers CSLA 3.x, not the current 4.0 release. However most of the priciples remain the same with some changes to implementation detail.

Answer (score 0):

I learned from [C# 2008 Business Objects](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430210192) and it's a great book. Besides learning the framework, you can learn a lot of oop principles that you can use outside the csla.net.

Comment: Duplicate of the other answer